# How to change reference category for INDEPENDENT variables in multinomial logistic regression in SPSS?

Tags: reference, logistic-regression, spss, categorical

It seems that SPSS does not allow to change reference category for categorical predictors in multinomial logistic regression. I guess that it should be possible using syntax editor (NOMREG function), anyone knows which is the right syntax to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Alberto